# Trace of $(A-2I_4)^{10}+(A+I_4)^7$

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

Given matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  -1 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
  5 & -2 & -1 & 1  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
 \end{pmatrix}$.

a)Find Jordan matrix $J$ of A.

b)Find trace of $(A-2I_4)^{10}+(A+I_4)^7$

a)In standard way I found $J=\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 2 & 1  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 2 
 \end{pmatrix}$

But how to do b)?

Comment: Substitute $A=C^{-1}JC$ into $(A-2I_2)^{10}+(A+I_4)^7$.

Comment: Hint: ${\rm Tr}(A \pm I)^m = {\rm Tr}(J \pm I)^m$.